# DataFrame not considering column A due to cell A1 is blank

Tags: python, pandas, csv, glob

I'm trying to import all raw data (csv files) into one DataFrame, and since the raw data file have some useless lines, I like to delete them by "drop", however for the row with first column is a blank cell. I'm unable to delete it, and the dataframe doesn't recognize that column.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np   
import glob
import os

#Determine file path for index weighting files
pathwgt=r'//10.27.36.181/etf/Bill/Quant/AxJ_Weight'
filenames = glob.glob(pathwgt + "/*.csv")

#declare data frame
dfwgt=pd.DataFrame()

#consolidate all files into one data frame
for filename in filenames:
    dfwgt=dfwgt.replace('',np.NaN)
    dfwgt=dfwgt.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

dfwgt=dfwgt.drop(['Symbol','Company'])
```

now my cell A1 in excel is blank, and B1 has a string, where I like to delete the entire row 1. The dataFrame shape is [124544 rows x 6 columns], where it suppose to be [124544 rows x 7 columns]

Comment: Can you add data samples, 3-4 rows and desired output?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Remember to add the appropriate language tag.

Comment: Its unclear do you need to delete the column or the row? You dont need to drop the rows. Just select the rows ignoring what you dont want.

Comment: Hi Jezrael, yes I can add the heading, however since dataframe only consider it as 6 columns, I'm unable to add the first column header...

Comment: @BillSun - Do you need `pd.read_csv(filename).reset_index()` ? It is really hard answering, because data depending problem.

Comment: Also quite confusing that you use the term `excel` but you use `pd.read_csv()` this function would rename the blank column to `'Unnamed: 0'` - lastly `dfwgt` is a shit variable name.

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal, Yes, that's exactly my problem, I got 'Unnamed :0' in my output. You mentioned that I used pd.read_csv(), that's because my source files are in csv format.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few solutions to your problem:

#### Remove row and header:

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv', skiprows=1, header=None)
```

This create a DataFrame with column names identified by a number. (e.g. from `0 -> 3`)

---

#### Drop column:

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Will result in have the unnamed column being assigned the name `'Unnamed: 0'` you can drop this column by doing the following:

```
df = df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)
```

---

#### Change name:

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Alternatively:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': 'new_name'}
```

If the above doesn't solve your problem, then I am struggling to understand your question.